# Error: Failed to query available provider packages when I run terraform init command

Tags: terraform

So I am following [Terrafom's official page](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli) to install and start with Terraform, but when I come to terraform init command, I am getting the following error.

Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider kreuzwerker/docker: could not connect to registry.terraform.io:
│ Failed to request discovery document: Get "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": dial tcp: lookup
│ registry.terraform.io on 192.168.0.1:53: server misbehaving

Comment: Looks like dns resolved terraform.io to an RFC 1918 address.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be with the network connectivity. If you are using a VPN stop it and then retry the command terraform init.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using an Apple M1 chip, I posted this answer elsewhere:

I am using a Macbook with an M1 chip as well and kept facing the same error. To fix, I had to uninstall terraform "brew uninstall terraform", follow these instructions https://benobi.one/posts/running_brew_on_m1_for_x86/, run "ibrew install hashicorp/tap/terraform".

Although "terraform version" will provide the same output as before, it now works. For me at least. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31464839)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when running `terraform init` for a new AWS resource. I get the error below:

```
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "4.9.0"...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

I think it is a temporary network issue.

All I had to do was to upgrade the Terraform version from 1.17 to 1.18 using the command:

```
brew upgrade terraform
```

And then tried to run `terraform init` again. Waited for some minutes and it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same error while running **terraform init** in VS code.

Please try by Closing all open terminals and try command in new terminal. This solved my issue.

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

here's a similar error I got and how I managed to solve it.

Error:
Solving error:
Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain
│ provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm: failed to instantiate provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm" to obtain schema: fork/exec
│ .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.72.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.72.0_x5:
│ permission denied..

Solution (local)

- In your terraform folder run the following command to find your permissions: ls -l .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\azurerm\3.72.0\windows_386
- Then run the PowerShell command to setup permissions: icacls .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\azurerm\3.72.0\windows_386
- See https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409220280339-Error-Could-not-load-plugin-permission-denied-or-exec-format-error

Solution (Azure DevOps Pipeline)

- Solution for ADO: using Ubuntu agents, (linux uses "/" instead of " \ "), Terraform couldn't find the file. Switching to the correct agent (in my case Windows) solved it

I hope this helps